# How to get current route in react-router 2.0.0-rc5

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have a router like below:

```
<Router history={hashHistory}>
    <Route path="/" component={App}>
        <IndexRoute component={Index}/>
        <Route path="login" component={Login}/>
    </Route>
</Router>
```

Here's what I want to achieve :

1. Redirect user to `/login` if not logged in
2. If user tried to access `/login` when they are already logged in, redirect them to root `/`

so now I'm trying to check user's state in `App`'s `componentDidMount`, then do something like:

```
if (!user.isLoggedIn) {
    this.context.router.push('login')
} else if(currentRoute == 'login') {
    this.context.router.push('/')
}
```

The problem here is I can't find the API to get current route.

I found [this closed issue](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/issues/119) suggested using Router.ActiveState mixin and route handlers, but it looks like these two solutions are now deprecated.

Answer (score 112, accepted):

After reading some more document, I found the solution:

https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/location.md

I just need to access the injected property `location` of the instance of the component like:

```
var currentLocation = this.props.location.pathname
```

Comment: It is unavailable in some child components, but I managed to pass them via prop.

Comment: For me (v2.8.1), it was available via `this.state.location.pathname` (instead of props).

Comment: You need to make sure to add this to your component

    `static contextTypes = {
      router: React.PropTypes.object
    }`

Comment: if it is unavailable in your child components, you just need to wrap using withRouter()

Comment: Thanks, the link is helpful!

Answer (score 27):

You can get the current route using

```
const currentRoute = this.props.routes[this.props.routes.length - 1];
```

...which gives you access to the props from the lowest-level active `<Route ...>` component.

Given...

```
<Route path="childpath" component={ChildComponent} />
```

`currentRoute.path` returns `'childpath'` and `currentRoute.component` returns `function _class() { ... }`.

Comment: This is a great method, as it retains any custom properties defined on the route. `this.props.location` loses these custom properties.

Comment: And to get previous route (i.e. for a back button + label) you can use `this.props.routes.length - 2`

Answer (score 10):

If you use the history,then Router put everything into the location from the history,such as:

```
this.props.location.pathname;
this.props.location.query;
```

get it?

Comment: may be you can extend you answer, to have more input and some references? right now it's way too general

Answer (score 8):

As of version 3.0.0, you can get the current route by calling:

> this.context.router.location.pathname

Sample code is below:

```
var NavLink = React.createClass({
    contextTypes: {
        router: React.PropTypes.object
    },

    render() {   
        return (
            <Link {...this.props}></Link>
        );
    }
});
```

Answer (score 7):

For any users having the same issue in 2017, I solved it the following way:

```
NavBar.contextTypes = {
    router: React.PropTypes.object,
    location: React.PropTypes.object
}
```

and use it like this:

```
componentDidMount () {
    console.log(this.context.location.pathname);
}
```

Comment: As `PropTypes` is now a standalone dependency, thought to add:

`import PropTypes from 'prop-types'; ... NavBar.contextTypes = { router: PropTypes.object, location: PropTypes.object };`

Answer (score 4):

In `App.js` add the below code and try

```
window.location.pathname
```

Comment: this becomes stale during a redirect and is only updated after the redirect happens

Answer (score 2):

You could use the 'isActive' prop like so:

```
const { router } = this.context;
if (router.isActive('/login')) {
    router.push('/');
}
```

isActive will return a true or false.

Tested with react-router 2.7

Answer (score 0):

Works for me in the same way:

```
...
<MyComponent {...this.props}>
  <Route path="path1" name="pname1" component="FirstPath">
  ...
</MyComponent>
...
```

And then, I can access "this.props.location.pathname" in the MyComponent function.

I forgot that it was I am...))) Following link describes more for make navigation bar etc.: [react router this.props.location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42010053/react-router-this-props-location)

Answer (score 0):

Try grabbing the path using:
`document.location.pathname`

In Javascript you can the current URL in parts. Check out:
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/get-url-and-url-parts-in-javascript/