# react router this.props.location

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I need a help with react-router v2+ 
I have to change class of navbar when route changed 
for example for `route /profile className` will be `"profile-header"` 
I tried to use `this.props.location` in navbar component but it shows `undefined`

Hope your help

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Your `navbar` component (as you described it in your question) is probably not the route component, right? By `route component` I mean the one that you use in your `react-router` configuration that is loaded for a specific route.

`this.props.location` is accessible only on such `route component`, so you need to pass it down to your `navbar`.

**Let's take an example:**

Your router config:

```
<Router>
    <Route path="/" component={App}>
    // ...
</Router
```

Route component `App`:

```
class App extends React.Component{
  // ...
  render() {
    return <Navbar location={this.props.location}/>
  }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

There could be a scenario where you may not have access to props.location to pass to the nav component.

Take for example - We had a header component in our project which was included in the routing switch to make it available to all routes.

```
<Switch>
  <Fragment>
    <Header/>
    <Route path='..' component={...}/>
    <Route path='..' component={...}/>
  </Fragment>
</Switch>
```

In the above scenario there is no way to pass the location data to the Header component.

A better solution would be to us the withRouter HOC when a component is not being rendered by your router.
You will still have access to the router properties history, match and location when you wrap it in the withRouter HOC:

```
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom'
.... 
....
export default withRouter(ThisComponent)
```

Comment: `export default withRouter(ThisComponent)` : What will be ThisComponent. `Header`?

Comment: Yes, in order to access location data inside Header

Comment: Can you answer https://stackoverflow.com/q/59262734/1994950 ?

Comment: Thanks, bro! Ive tried almost all solutions and yours was the only one that have worked in my case

Answer (score 2):

**react-router v4**

From [documentation](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/basic-components):

> 1. `<Route>` `component` property should be used, when you have an existing component. `<Route>` `render` property takes an inline function, that returns html.
> 2. A `<Route>` with no `path` will always match.

Based on this, we can make a `<Route>` wrapper to *any level* of your html structure. It will always be displayed and have access to the location object.

As per your request, if a user comes to `/profile` page, the `<header>` will have `profile-header` class name.

```
<Router>
    <Route render={({ location }) =>
        <header className={location.pathname.replace(/\//g, '') + '-header'}>
            // header content...
        </header>

        <div id="content"></div>

        <footer></footer>
    } />
</Router>
```

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't solve it with the solutions given here and here is what worked for me:

I imported `history` into my component and assigned `history.location.pathname` to a variable which I later used for dynamic style manipulation.

Answer (score 0):

In case you are rendering the component with pre-defined location.state values, first set your state with props.location.state then use your state data in your elements.

Comment: I tried it in `render()` method. I tried to set state from `props.location`. But it gave infinite loop of rendering as `setState() -> render() -> serState() -> render() ...` likewise. So better to use approach mentioned at https://stackoverflow.com/a/59264602/1994950 answer