# Not able to use props to query API in react js

Tags: reactjs, react-component, zomato-api

I have `Restaurants` component which is responsible for listing restaurants from Zomato Dev APIs. I have passed `Category` and `City` from other components to `Restaurants` component.

I am opening `Restaurants` component with below code :

```
this.props.history.push(
        {
            pathname : '/restaurants', 
            valueCategory : this.props.location.valueA,  // CATEGORY
            valueCity : this.state.cities[index] // CITY
        });
```

I want to use these `valueCategory` and `valueCity` in calling `/search` api.

Code :

```
class Restaurants extends React.Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.componentDidMount = this.componentDidMount.bind(this);
    this.getRestaurants = this.getRestaurants.bind(this);
}

componentDidMount() {
    // I AM GETTING ERROR 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined' ON THIS LINE
    console.log("Component Did Mount Restaurant : " + this.props.location.valueCity.name);
}

 componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState, snapshot){
    console.log("Component Did Update :", prevProps); 
    //THIS PRINTS prevProps, WHICH CONTAINS valueCity and valueCategory but I am unable to access them
    return false;
}

render() {
    let category, city;
    category = '';
    city = '';

    if(!isUndefined(this.props.location.valueCategory)) {
        category = <p>You selected Category as : {this.props.location.valueCategory.categories.name}</p>;
    }

    if(!isUndefined(this.props.location.valueCity)) {
    // STRANGLY, THIS LINE WORKS FINE! WHEN I AM ACCESSING valueCity.name
        city = <p>You selected City as : {this.props.location.valueCity.name}</p>;
    }

    console.log(this.props.location);
    return (
        <div> 
            {category}
            {city}
        </div>
    );
}
}
```

[image]

My question is :

- I am able to access `{this.props.location.valueCity.name}` in `render()` method
- But I am not able to access the same in `componentDidMount()` or any other method? I am getting crash

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

Comment: Is your location accessible right on rendering or it's fetched?

Comment: componentDidMount will be called immediately after the first render.So may be your network is taking some time to load the data...but ,your trying to access the data which is the result of api call right?...Try to add check before accessing object property..For example:
const { location = {} } = this.props;
const {valueCity = {} } = location || {};
const {name = {}} = valueCity || {}.

or you can use lodash get

Comment: @RajeshKumaran No, I am not trying to access API result. I am trying to access `props` passed from top level component. I have not called API until now.

Comment: @MaciejTrojniarz location is accessible in `render()` method

Comment: the error is due to your props doesn't have the key named valueCity inside location.

Comment: can u print the props inside componentDidMount and check whether you have valueCity inside location prop

Comment: When I added `console.log("Component Did Mount Restaurant : " + this.props);` in `componentDidMount()`, it prints `Component Did Mount Restaurant : [object Object]`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried componentDidUpdate life cycle method? compare the props incoming to this method

```
        this.state={
        valueCategory:"",
        valueCity:"" //you can chose any data type, 
        checker:true  
        }

        this.stateUpdater(prevProps){
           let valueCategory={this.props};
           let valueCity={this.props};

           if(this.props.valueCategory===undefined){/*check the data  
           what is incoming and use condition accrodingly*/ 

           this.setState({valueCategory:prevProps.location.valueCategory
           ,checker:false})
           }else{
             //no update
              this.setState({checker:false})
            }
        componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState, snapshot){
           console.log("see the props",prevProps,this.props);
           if(this.state.checker)              
              this.stateUpdater(prevProps);
           else{
              console.log("do nothing") 
           }
           return false;
       }
```

**check and let me know

Comment: But put a condition there ,otherwise it will keep setting state,keep coding

Comment: can you screen shot your output?

Comment: Basically, This lifecycle method is not getting called for me currently

Comment: can you share the updated component code please? with this method

Comment: I have updated question and also posted screenshot. Please have a look

Comment: I am updating my reply with an idea ,let me know if it works or not,but we have to use state,check once.

Comment: In line `this.setState({valueCategory:prevProps.location.valueCategory.name ,checker:false})`, It is giving same error, unable to read property `'name'`

Comment: as per the screenshot ,you are getting prevProps inside componentDidUpdate,i dont understand why you are not able to pass that to that function

Comment: Yes, It got printed in console without any issue. But, I am unable to access it.

Comment: you can not access prevProps outside componentDidUpdate,that's why you need to pass to that function and convert it into state,then use the state data in your component

Comment: After passing the props, i received in `prevProp` parameter in `stateUpdater(prevProp)` function, but is not getting accessed. Your posted code won't work, if you pass any thing in `props.location` in this component

Comment: hey i am sorry i did not write the location in the code like "prevProps.location.valueCategory",i updated the reply my bad!!

Comment: Hey did you run your code? It will give access error at `location.valueCategory.name`

Comment: can you please post that error,i am sorry bro ,its taking longer than expected