# Get current router in react-router v4

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Is there a way in react router V4 API to get the current Router ?

The [withRouter](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/withRouter) HOC doesn't seems to provide it.

Comment: Maybe here your answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42253277/react-router-v4-how-to-get-current-route?answertab=active#tab-top -- by Con Posidielov