# react router hosting with sub folders issues

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

I am using react router with my application and everything works fine locally. Below is my code. The issue is when I host it online it is in a `my-application` subdirectory:

> https://www.example.com/my-application

This is breaking the code and it is not functioning as it should.

can anyone advise how to fix this issue? If there is anything unclear please feel free to ask. I have tried countless approaches but cannot get it to work. One answer can be seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42253277/react-router-v4-how-to-get-current-route).

the issue I am getting is that with the current code it navigates to `https://www.example.com/test` as opposed to `https://www.example.com/my-application/test`. I thought if I hardcoded in the url it would work but this also breaks the application.

The code below is slightly whittled down to remove superfluous code.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components'
import { Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom'


const Home = ({ avatarUrl }) => {
  return (
      <div>
         <Route exact path="/" component={Overview}/>
         <Route path="/test" component={Test}/>
      </div>
  );
};

class App extends Component {

  render() {

    return (
      <section>
        <Nav avatarUrl={ this.props.avatarUrl }/>
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/example" component={Example}/>
          <Route path="/" render={()=><Home
            avatarUrl={ avatarUrl }
          />}/>

        </Switch>
      </section>
    )
  }
}

export default App
```

Comment: Before going any further, what issue are you getting ?

Comment: updated code @MohamedELAYADI

Comment: This is because you are declaring  your  paths as /exemple /test, it's natural to redirect to the server root.

Comment: take a look at [this](https://medium.com/@svinkle/how-to-deploy-a-react-app-to-a-subdirectory-f694d46427c1)

Comment: @MohamedELAYADI brilliant that works

Comment: Glad your  problem is  resolved, good luck buddy :)

Answer (score 0):

Apply config changes pacakage.json add homepage page as your folder name

Answer (score 0):

To solve this I just did two things:

1. Added "hostname": "https://www.example.com/my-application" at the top of package.json.
2. Added basename="my-application" to the BrowserRouter e.g. `<BrowserRouter basename="my-application">`

Note: I created the project using create-react-app. I am using react version 18 and react-router version 6.