# React Router V4 Get Current Path

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

How can I get the current path using react router v4?

I have tried the following to no avail:

```
const currentLocation = this.props.location.pathname;
```

Error: `Cannot read property 'pathname' of undefined`

Here is my Routes.js file:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {  BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import configureStore from './Store';
import LevelOne from './containers/LevelOne';
import LevelTwo from './containers/LevelTwo';
import LevelThree from './containers/LevelThree';
import CreateProfile from './containers/Profile/CreateProfile';
import WhosWatching from './containers/Profile/WhosWatching';
import ProfileNameAvatar from './containers/Profile/ProfileNameAvatar';
import FavouriteGenres from './containers/Profile/FavouriteGenres';
import FourZeroFour from './containers/404';

import Header from './components/Header';

const store = configureStore();

const navItems = [
  {
    title:"For You",
    to: "/for-you"
  },
  {
    title:"Movies",
    to: "/movies"
  },
  {
    title:"Series",
    to: "/series"
  },
  {
    title:"TV Shows",
    to: "/tv-Shows"
  },
  {
    title:"Subscriptions",
    to: "/subscriptions"
  },
  {
    title:"Live TV",
    to: "/live-tv"
  }
]

export default class Routes extends Component {
  state = {
    theme: 'light'
  }

  header = React.createRef();

  setTheme = (theme) => {
    this.setState({
      theme: theme,
    });
  }

  render() {
    const currentLocation = this.props.location.pathname;
    console.log("location", currentLocation);
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <Router ref='router'>
          <div className='app'>
            {/*<Header navItems={navItems} theme={this.state.theme} ref={this.header} />*/}
            <Switch>
              <Route exact path="/" render={(props) => (
                <LevelOne {...props} setTheme={this.setTheme} />
              )}/>
              <Route exact path="/for-you" render={(props) => (
                <LevelTwo {...props} setTheme={this.setTheme} />
              )}/>
              <Route exact path="/for-you/view-all" render={(props) => (
                <LevelThree {...props} setTheme={this.setTheme} innerRef={this.header} />
              )}/>
              <Route exact path="/profile/create-profile" render={(props) => (
                <CreateProfile {...props} />
              )}/>
              <Route exact path="/profile/whos-watching" render={(props) => (
                <WhosWatching {...props} />
              )}/>
              <Route exact path="/profile/profile-name-avatar" render={(props) => (
                <ProfileNameAvatar {...props} />
              )}/>
              <Route exact path="/profile/favourite-genres" render={(props) => (
                <FavouriteGenres {...props} />
              )}/>
              <Route component={FourZeroFour} />
            </Switch>
          </div>
        </Router>
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You will only have access to `this.props.location` in a `Route` component (as the prop is passed to the component from it).

You can get the current path with `window.location.pathname` outside of the `Router`, though it's likely that you are doing something wrong if you are accessing the path here.

For children of `Router`, you can access the location by wrapping it around [`withRouter`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/withRouter) or pass the prop downwards from a `Route` component.

[Redux integration](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/deep-redux-integration) will also allow you to access the location from anywhere.

Comment: Thank you for this @riwu - exactly what I was after.

Comment: If you're looking to retrieve the exact Route with a reference like a key or a name, check https://stackoverflow.com/a/59217492/1702919

Comment: What if your component comes before the router and can't be inside the router ?

Answer (score 11):

Fast solution
Create a variable on your function:

```
var currentLocation = window.location.pathname;
```

and then in the `ul > li  className={(currentLocation == '/' ? 'active' : '')}`

**it worked for mee and is a quick solution.**

Comment: it will not build

Answer (score 4):

`this.props.match.path` should do the trick

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I replaced the currentLocation const with your suggestion and got an error with: Cannot read property 'path' of undefined

Comment: Sorry, my command was ment to be used inside of the Router Component i believe

Answer (score 3):

you can get the path directly from the `document` variable.

eg: `const path = document.location.pathname`