# ReactJS: onClick `window.location.href` return previous page value

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router

In my react project i need to make a condition on redux action according to the page location.

So i have used `window.location.href` to get value of the current page but it returns the last visited page value.

```
export const getBlog = (type, offset) => {
  console.log(window);
  console.log(window.location.pathname);
  if( window.location.pathname !== '/planner' ){
    return (dispatch) => {

        dispatch({ type: 'BLOG_LOADING_START'})

      axios.get(siteurl + TPW.CATEGORY_API + type, {
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' } })
        .then(response => {
        let ary =  response.data.slice(0, offset)
        dispatch({
            type: 'SET_BLOG_DATA',
            list: response.data,
            blogData: ary,
            total: response.data.length,
            offSetCnt: 3
        })
        dispatch({ type: 'BLOG_LOADING_DONE'})
      });
    }
  }
}
```

First `console.log(window)` screenshot; which returns an actual visited page location result.

[image]

Second `console.log(window.location.pathname)` which returns previous visited page value.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`window.location.pathname` always gives you the page you landed on. Since we are using `react-router` to get the current route you need to use `this.props.location`.

You can refer this answer for more clarity

[get location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50511111/react-router-v4-get-current-path/50511199)

Comment: It returns me a TypeError of `props` undefined while using a `this.props.location` in this redux function.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the console does not make a deep copy of window when you log it.
It loads the value when you expand the location node.

That explains why those two results differ.