# What is a better way to identify which route i am currently on with react-router 4

Tags: reactjs, routes, react-router, react-router-v4

I am building a react app and using react router 4. The navbar consists of links on left side and couple of buttons on the right hand side (We call it right tools).

Navbar is a part of layout.
Now these button are different for different pages. For eg  I have 3 pages  Dashboard, History and Admin. In Dashboard there is a Filter button, History will have Filter, Download. Admin will have no button.

In angular their is $state.current but cannot find anything similar in React router.

Matching url string is painful. Does anyone have a better solution to this ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React Router v4 - How to get current route?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42253277/react-router-v4-how-to-get-current-route)

Answer (score 5):

This was sort of explained, but I don't think it was super clear. It's really easy if you're using a functional component.

When importing the router, include 'useLocation'.

```
import { Link, useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';
```

And then instantiate it at the start of the component.

```
let location = useLocation();
```

Then whenever you need to use it, just call it.

```
console.log(location.pathname);
```

Easy!

Answer (score 0):

When you make use of `react-router`, you can identify which path you are currently on by simply reading the `location.pathname` from the props.

If the component in which you are trying to access `location.pathname` isn't connected to the `Route` directly or isn't receiving the `Router` props, you can wrap it with the `withRouter` HOC to access router props.

Also, router has a prop called as `match` which gives the closest match route information to the component that you are using that in

For example, in a Route configuration

```
<Route path="/" component={Home} />
```

**Home.jsx**

```
render() {
    console.log(this.props.match.path);
    return (
        <div>
             <Route path="/user" component={User}/>
        </div>
    )
}
```

So in the above case if you are visiting the url: `/user`, and if you log `this.props.match.url`, it will result in `/` which isn't the desired result that you might be looking for.

A way to get around this is to use `matchPath` method that is provided by `react-router`

A typical usage of it would be

```
const { match } = this.props;
let { hash } = window.location;
[hash] = hash.slice(1).split('?');
// match.path is the path that is matched till the parent
const customMatch = matchPath(hash, {
    path: `${match.path}user`,
    exact: false,
    strict: false
});
console.log(customMatch)
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple way which is working for me is here `this.props.match`
For explore it you can console it in your current component and it will provide all details to you.

```
  render() {
        console.warn("url details", this.props.match.params.id)
        return (
```

**keep in mind that**  You must console it in current main component for full path. If you will try to supportive component such as NAV or breadcrumb. it may not work property. and let me know if you have still issue.