# How to Hide Navbar items on URL Change?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-redux

I have a navbar component named Header which is called on almost every page of my web app, now I want some of the navbar items to disappear upon opening certain pages like I want nav items to disappear on http://localhost:3000/stories but must show on http://localhost:3000/, I have attached images.
For example I want "what is valu" and "How valu works?" disappear on /stories page
I have wrote a set state function on these items upon click, but the they work the second time when I click stories nav item.

```
operation()
{
  this.setState({showme:false})

}
 <Navbar className="fixed-top navbar-custom" color="white" light expand="lg">
        <Container>
          <NavbarBrand tag={Link} to='/'>
            <img src={logo} alt="logo" className="logo" />
          </NavbarBrand>

          <NavbarToggler onClick={this.toggle} />

          <Collapse isOpen={this.state.isOpen} navbar>
          { this.state.showme?
            <Nav className="mr-auto" navbar style={{cursor:'pointer'}}>
              <NavItem>
              <NavLink onClick={this.scrollToTop} className = "navlink-custom">What is Valu?</NavLink>
                </NavItem> 
              <NavItem>
                <NavLink onClick={this.scrollTo} className = "navlink-custom">How Valu work ?</NavLink>
              </NavItem>
            </Nav>
            :null
          }


            <Nav className="ml-auto" navbar  >
              <NavItem>
                <NavLink onClick={this.operation}  tag={Link} to='/stories' className = "navlink-custom">Stories</NavLink>
              </NavItem>
              <NavItem >
                <NavLink  tag={Link} to='/aboutus' className = "navlink-custom" Link to="/aboutus">About us</NavLink>
              </NavItem>
              <NavItem>
              <Link to="/signup">
                <button className="btn-login">
                  <div className="login">Register/login</div>
                </button>{' '}
                </Link>
              </NavItem>
            </Nav>
          </Collapse>
        </Container>
      </Navbar>
```

Routes.js
In the routes:

```
    const AppRouter = () =>
    { 
    return ( 
    <Router> 
    <Switch> 
    <Route exact path='/' component={App}/> 
    <Route path='/howvaluworks' component={HowValuWorks} /> 
    <Route path='/Footer' component={footer} /> 
    <Route path='/aboutus' component={AboutUs} /> 
    <Route path='/login' component={loginform}/> 
    <Route path='/signup' component={signupform}/>
    <Route path='/signup' component={signupform}/> 
    <Route path='/profile-tutorial' component={profiletutorial}/> 
    <Route path='/profile-account' component={profileaccount}/> 
    <Route path='/stories' component={stories}/> 
    <Route path='/profilelaunch' component={profilelaunch}/> 
  )};
```

Comment: I have updated my answer

Comment: Its working now thank you so much, I used this link to get route https://stackoverflow.com/a/51389622/10248999

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the condition based on the route location in the `componentWillReceiveProps`.

```
constructor(props){
 super(props);
  this.state = { 
    hideValu : 1
  };
 this.changeNavItem = this.changeNavItem.bind(this);
}

componentDidMount(){
 this.changeNavItem(this.props.location.pathname);
}

componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
 if(this.props.location.pathname !== nextProps.location.pathname){
   this.changeNavItem(nextProps.location.pathname); 
  }
}

changeNavItem(currentRoute){
  if(currentRoute == "\stories"){
       this.setState({
          hideValu : 0
       });
    }
}
```

In the navbar,

```
{ this.state.showme? <Nav className="mr-auto" navbar style={{cursor:'pointer'}}>
        this.state.hideValu && <div>
          <NavItem>
             <NavLink onClick={this.scrollToTop} className = "navlink-custom">What is 
             Valu?</NavLink>
          </NavItem> 
          <NavItem>
            <NavLink onClick={this.scrollTo} className = "navlink-custom">How Valu 
            work ?
            </NavLink>
          </NavItem>
        </div>
        </Nav>
        :null
      }
```

**UPDATE**

Wrap your routes with the component called `MainLayout` where you define you `header` and `footer` component.So that you the props.location value gets updated and you will have access to it.

```
  <Router>
        <Switch>
         <MainLayout>
            <Route exact path='/' component={App}/>
            <Route path='/howvaluworks' component={HowValuWorks} />
            <Route path='/Footer' component={footer} />
            <Route path='/aboutus' component={AboutUs} />
            <Route path='/login' component={loginform}/>
            <Route path='/signup' component={signupform}/>
            <Route path='/profile-tutorial' component={profiletutorial}/>
            <Route path='/profile-account' component={profileaccount}/>
            <Route path='/stories' component={stories}/>
            <Route path='/profilelaunch' component={profilelaunch}/>
            <Route path='/draft' component={draft}/>
            <Route path='/dashboard' component={dashboard}/>
            <Route path='/launchsurvey' component={launchsurvey}/>
          </MainLayout>
        </Switch>
    </Router>
```

**MainLayout.js**

```
import React from "react"
import Header  from '../containers/Header';
import Footer from "./Footer"

class MainLayout extends React.Component{
  render() {
      return(
         <div>
            <Header />
              <div className="appLayout">
                { this.props.children }
              </div>
            <Footer />
         </div>
      );
  }
}

export default MainLayout
```

Add also add `navbar` in the header component

Comment: I have added your Code but it says , "pathname" undefined, So where Do I have to initialize this path name, I am new to react so Bare me, If I am being Dumb in this situation.

Comment: I am using react-router-dom

Comment: `react-router-dom: 4.2.2` this is what i am using

Comment: Ok that's cool.Please share your custom `routes.js ` which handles your components.

Comment: I have added the file coding in my Question..!!

Comment: Your logic is working, but unfortunately its not getting its `path` value... Do you have any other way to do that, I have applied all the changes in project recommended by you !!

Answer (score 0):

If you want a fast solution. You can just use window.location.pathname to check your url and do some conditions like this

```
    this.state = {
  hideNavItems: false
}

componentDidMount() {
  if (window.location.pathname === '/stories') {
    this.setState({hideNavItems: true});
  }
}

render() {
  return (
    <Navbar className="fixed-top navbar-custom" color="white" light expand="lg">
      <Container>
        <NavbarBrand tag={Link} to='/'>
          <img src={logo} alt="logo" className="logo" />
        </NavbarBrand>

        <NavbarToggler onClick={this.toggle} />

        <Collapse isOpen={this.state.isOpen} navbar>
        { !this.state.hideNavItems 
          ? (<span>
              <Nav className="mr-auto" navbar style={{cursor:'pointer'}}>
                <NavItem>
                  <NavLink onClick={this.scrollToTop} className = "navlink-custom">What is Valu?</NavLink>
                </NavItem> 
                <NavItem>
                  <NavLink onClick={this.scrollTo} className = "navlink-custom">How Valu work ?</NavLink>
                </NavItem>
              </Nav>
            </span>)
          : null
        }


          <Nav className="ml-auto" navbar  >
            <NavItem>
              <NavLink onClick={this.operation}  tag={Link} to='/stories' className = "navlink-custom">Stories</NavLink>
            </NavItem>
            <NavItem >
              <NavLink  tag={Link} to='/aboutus' className = "navlink-custom" Link to="/aboutus">About us</NavLink>
            </NavItem>
            <NavItem>
            <Link to="/signup">
              <button className="btn-login">
                <div className="login">Register/login</div>
              </button>{' '}
              </Link>
            </NavItem>
          </Nav>
        </Collapse>
      </Container>
    </Navbar>
  )
}
```