# How to get route name without Forward Slash in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, dom

I have created a component where I am getting Route name through `window.location.pathname` it is working fine and gives me a route name but I want to remove forward slash `/` from route name . I am beginner to ReactJS , Could someone please help me how to solve this problem ?

```
const pathName=window.location.pathname;
```

Comment: Leading or trailing slash?

Comment: in react router 2 you can do `this.props.routes[this.props.routes.length-1]` to get current route.

Comment: @IsaacVidrine that's a pretty old version though, the current react router version is v5. Does the same code work in up to date versions?

Comment: @SterlingArcher can't confirm v5 but [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43908438/8167494) seems to be the accepted answer for v4.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [**substr**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr) to take string after `/` only

```js
const pathName= window.location.pathname.substr(1,)

console.log(pathName)
```