# How to get what url I am from by react-router

Tags: typescript, react-redux, react-router-dom

I am currently working on react-redux with react-router, and one of my page need to know which page user clicked to direct to this new page.

Is there a way that I can get the information about the url of previous page by react-router?

Comment: There are multiple ways to solve it. Show some code of what you tried so far.

Comment: this might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42253277/react-router-v4-how-to-get-current-route

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React Router v4 - How to get current route?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42253277/react-router-v4-how-to-get-current-route)

Comment: Thank you everyone. I solved it by passing a ref[?=].

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to save the previous location in the getDerivedStateFromProps method.

```
static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, prevState) {
    if (prevState.location === //your path){
        ...
    }
    return null;
};
```

More info here: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#static-getderivedstatefromprops