# Is there a function in react to hide a component based on the website path?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

In my react app I currently have this:

```
<Router>
    <div class Name="App">
      <Route path="/" exact component={PersonList} />
      <Route path="/rules" exact component={RulesPage} />
      <Route path="/roles" exact component={RolesPage} />
      <Route path="/test" exact component={Test} />
      <Footer />
    </div>
  </Router>
```

However I want the footer element to be hidden if the route path is "/test"
It would be a lot cleaner than writing:

```
<Route path="/roles" exact component={Footer} />
<Route path="/rules" exact component={Footer} />
<Route path="/" exact component={Footer} />
```

If anyone knows the function to do this it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42253277/react-router-v4-how-to-get-current-route

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a higher-order component that renders a component with a footer and then you could render that higher-order component at all the paths other than `/test`.

Higher-order component just takes a component that should be displayed with a `Footer` component and returns another component that just renders the wrapped component along with the `Footer` component.

```
function WithFooter(WrappedComponent) {
  const EnhancedComponent = (props) => {
    return (
      <>
        <WrappedComponent {...props} />
        <Footer />
      </>
    );
  };

  return EnhancedComponent;
}
```

After this, instead of exporting `PersonList` component, you need to export the component returned by calling `WithFooter` higher-order component as shown below:

```
function PersonList() {
  ...
}

export default WithFooter(PersonList);
```

You need to do the same for other components as well that should be rendered with a `Footer`.

With higher-order component all set-up, your routes definition don't need to change:

```
<Router>
   <Route path="/" exact component={PersonList)} />
   <Route path="/rules" exact component={RulesPage} />
   <Route path="/roles" exact component={RolesPage} />
   <Route path="/test" exact component={Test} />
</Router>
```

Alternative solution is to conditionally render the `Footer` component after checking the URL using `window.location` or `useParams()` hook provided by `react-router-dom` but `useParams()` will only work if your component is rendered using react router. In your case, you will need `window.location`.

Comment: `withFooter` is not defined

Comment: you need to write `withFooter` higher-order component, its not a built-in component

Comment: In case you are not clear as to how you could implement the higher-order component and make it all work, I have added more details of how you could implement the higher-order component and other changes you need to do.

Answer (score 0):

In your `Footer` component you could just check if the `window.location.pathname` includes `/test` and just return `null`

Comment: ``` if(window.location.pathname.includes === "/test"){
    return(
      null
    )
}
``` I added this, still shows up on the website

Answer (score 0):

Another option incase you are not familiar with the HOC pattern is to render the `<Footer/>` component inside only those components that need it rather than at the top level.