# how to hide a component on specific routes in react.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

[image: this is the screenshot of the app.js file]
I want to hide my navbar when the route is at some specific routes, I want the logic for hiding the nav be in the app.js:-

```
export default function App() {

    return (
        <React.StrictMode>
            <Router>
                <NavBar />
                <Routes />
                <Footer />
            </Router>
        </React.StrictMode>
    );
};
```

Comment: Seems like this might be useful for you https://stackoverflow.com/a/60736742/6130275

Comment: I thought this was outdated because it was asked 4 years ago

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted regarding the error you mentioned in comments, it's caused by the `BrowerRouter` as its being used in the same file.

**Solution**:

Moving `BrowserRouter` one level up will solve as by the time you invoke `useLocation()` the router also comes into the picture.

So the `index.js` file should be like

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Router>
    <App />
    </Router>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById("root")
)
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use useLocation hook from react-router-dom to identify the path where you want to hide the navbar.

```
export default function App() {
    const { pathname } = useLocation();
    return (
        <>
              { pathname === "/some-path" ? null : <NavBar />  }
                <Routes />
                <Footer />
        </>
    );
};
```

**Edit**

Render the app component inside the index.js file, like this.

```js
 
 ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Router>
      <App />
    </Router>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

I think you forgot to remove the router from the app.js file

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'location' of undefined this error comes up and I have imported useLocation from react-router-dom

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of your code?
shahzaibmohammad07@gmail.com

Comment: which version of react-router-dom is it?

Comment: "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",

Comment: I got the issue,  wrap your App component with the router.

render( <Router> <App /> </Router>, appDiv )

Comment: I have edit the answer have a look at that.

Comment: your updated answer worked but now when I use react-router to the specific page the navbar stays in its initial state i.e if I want to hide the navbar in the signup page and route to the signup page from another page the navbar doesn't unmount but when I reload the signup page the navbar disappears and after that, if I route to another page from the signup page the navbar stays hidden, I think it always needs a refresh to update, so is their a fix??