# How can I get the correct current path in React using react router 4.2.2's withRouter?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

So I have some files:

**App.js**

```
class App extends React.Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <div >
                <NavBar />
                <Main />
            </div>
        );
    }

}

export default App;
```

**NavBar.js**

```
class NavBar extends React.Component {

  render() {
    console.log(this.props.match)
    return (
      <div className="navbar-fixed">
        <nav className="light-blue lighten-1">
          <div className="nav-wrapper container">
            <a className="brand-logo">Logo</a>
            <ul id="nav-mobile" className="right hide-on-med-and-down">
              <li><NavLink exact to="/characters" activeClassName="active">Characters</NavLink></li>
              <li><NavLink exact to="/locations" activeClassName="active">Locations</NavLink></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </nav>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default withRouter(NavBar);
```

**Main.js**

```
class Main extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Switch>
                <Route exact path="/characters" component={Characters}/>
                <Route exact path="/locations" component={Locations}/>
            </Switch>
        );
    }
}

export default Main;
```

The routing works, though in NavBar file, I have the `console.log(this.props.match)` line and I always get the same path and the `activeClassName` does not even work.

Whenever I change locations, the output is always:

```
{
    path: "/", 
    url: "/", 
    params: {…}, 
    isExact: false
}
```

The only thing that changes is the key `isExact`.

I can access the pathname now with `this.props.location`, though I have to make my own login for the active classnames to work.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get current route in react-router 2.0.0-rc5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35031911/how-to-get-current-route-in-react-router-2-0-0-rc5)

Answer (score 1):

`this.props.match` gives you the match parameters for the closest matching parent and not the Route in children that is matching, since `App` is at top level and matches with `path='/'`, printing it in `Navbar` will always return you

```
{
    path: "/", 
    url: "/", 
    params: {…}, 
    isExact: false
}
```

Now say in your case `Characters` component has a subRoute(note that you should not be using exact keyword if you have nested Routes within it),which you define as

```
render() {
   return (
      <div>
          {/* other stuff*/}
          <Route path={`${this.props.match.path}/:characterId`} component={Character} />
      </div>
   )
}
```

In this case even though your url maybe `/characters/character-1`, `console.log(this.props.match)` in character component will return you

```
{
    path: "/character", 
    url: "/character", 
    params: {…}, 
    isExact: false
}
```

As far as a changing value of `isExact` is considered, it returns you `true of false` based on the fact the entire url matches your Route url or not

Answer (score 0):

Using `withRouter` appends the [location](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/location.md) object to the component Properties:

```
class NavBar extends React.Component {
  // just for reference
  static propTypes = {
    location: PropTypes.object
  }

  render() {
    console.log("Location", this.props.location);
    return (
      <div className="navbar-fixed">
        <nav className="light-blue lighten-1">
          <div className="nav-wrapper container">
            <a className="brand-logo">Logo</a>
            <ul id="nav-mobile" className="right hide-on-med-and-down">
              <li><NavLink exact to="/characters" activeClassName="active">Characters</NavLink></li>
              <li><NavLink exact to="/locations" activeClassName="active">Locations</NavLink></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </nav>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default withRouter(NavBar);
```

The `props.location` has the shape:

```
{
  key: 'ac3df4',
  pathname: '/somewhere',
  search: '?some=search-string',
  hash: '#howdy',
  state: {
    [userDefined]: true
  }
}
```