# How can I conditionally render particular html sections depending on the Route

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm using `React` for this project.

I have got a `Help` section on my website, This help section has about 50+ articles. If you go to `/help-open-account` I want to render some `html` and if I go to `/fraud` I want to display different `html` it is all dynamic content so its using the same js file hence why I want to render depending on the link.

I know how to use the conditional statements but how can I use the current url as a statement so like `path="/(?!help--lostMyCard)"` if its currently on that url then render the content this content instead of `x` content.

The app.js file has this following code ->

```
<BrowserRouter>
    <Switch>
       <Route path="/" exact component={HelpSupport} />
       <Route to="/help-articles" component={HelpArticles} />
    </Switch>
</BrowserRouter>
```

Would the code above be the only way to conditionally render content? As this is rendering full components and I wanted to conditionally render subcomponents within them.

Just to clarify, I know how to use the routes and so on, but thats not the question, the question is when you are in a component for example you are in the Help components, can I conditionally render content depending on my Route and if so how?

[image]

So the HelpfulArticles I want to render that if my route is X but if my route is Y then render this other component?

Comment: change to `<Route path="/help-articles" component={HelpArticles} />`

Comment: What I mean is when you are in a component, is there a way to use the Route for conditional rendering?

Comment: So for example the component `HelpArticles` is built with sub components. Inside that component I want to be able to say if Route === fraud <- exmaple then I render the fruad html template if the route is lost-myCard then I render the other component? @JSEngine

Comment: @JSEngine Image added with a better question maybe helps you understand my question better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that you want to access route information in component.

It seems that what you are looking for has already been solved here
[How to get current route in react-router 2.0.0-rc5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35031911/how-to-get-current-route-in-react-router-2-0-0-rc5)

For more information - 
Someone can club understanding with link here https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html in addition to above stackoverflow link i have mentioned in this comment to completely solve such problem.

Comment: This seems to solve my issue, thank you. Maybe there is a cleaner way though to find the route rather than `props.location.pathname` but if not that will be perfect, thanks.

Comment: Please always add better solution that helps other debuggers.

Answer (score 1):

if I understood correctly you want to add more routes based on your path:

Here below let's say *help-articles* has subpages that might have different HTML to render.

```
<BrowserRouter>
<Switch>
   <Route path="/" exact component={HelpSupport} />
   <Route path="/help-articles/:subpage?" component={HelpArticles} />
</Switch>
```

SO first to add subpage optional parameter.

Then in your *HelpArticles* component render method:

```
return {

 const {match} = this.props;
 const {params} = match;

  if(!params.subpage) {
    return <div> no subpage routes</div>
  }else if(params.subpage === "fruits") {
    return <FruitsHelper>
  } else if(params.subpage === "veg") {
    return <VegsHelper>
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

update the code here,

```
<BrowserRouter>
    <Switch>
       <Route path="/" exact component={HelpSupport} />
       // not `to`, it is `path`
       <Route path="/help-articles" component={HelpArticles} />
    </Switch>
</BrowserRouter>
```

now, you can update `HelpArticles` component like below,

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import List, { LostMyCard, LockedAccount } from "../custom/help";

class HelpArticles extends Component {

  _renderArticle() {
    const { location: { pathname } } = this.props;

    // render the components by comparing the url, here you can use switch too.

    if ((pathname || "").includes("lostMyCard")) {
      return <LostMyCard />
    }

    if ((pathname || "").includes("locked-account")) {
      return <LockedAccount />
    }

    // if no case is match then default component for listing the articles.
    return <List />

  }

  render() {

    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        {this._renderArticle()}
      </React.Fragment>
    )
  }
}


export default HelpArticles;
```